# Source Midrash - why the first letter of the Tenach is a Bet

Tags: blessing, midrash, parashat-bereishit, aleph-bet-letters, curse

What's the source of the Midrash that talks about the reason why the letter Bet was chosen as the first letter of the Tenach and not the Alef? The reason being given in this Midrash is that it is because the letter Bet is the first letter of Bracha (blessing) and the letter Alef is the first letter of Arur (curse).

Answer (score 7):

[Yerushalmi Chagigah](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%90) 2:1,

> דבר אחר ולמה בבי"ת שהוא בלשון ברכה ולא באל"ף שהוא לשון ארירה אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא איני בורא את עולמי אלא בבי"ת שלא יהו כל באי העולם אומרין היאך העולם יכול לעמוד ונברא בלשון ארירה אלא הריני בורא אותו בבי"ת בלשון ברכה ואולי יעמוד.‏

[Tanchuma Bereishis](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA) 5,

> למה פתח בברייתו של עולם בבי"ת ולא באל"ף והלא א' ראש לכל האותיות אלא לפי שהאל"ף לשון ארור וב' לשון ברוך אמר הקב"ה אברא את העולם בלשון ברוך ומה כשנברא בלשון ברוך בני אדם מכעיסין ליוצרם בלשון ארור עאכ"ו.‏

[Bereishis Rabba](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%99) 1:10

> ד"א ולמה בב' שהוא לשון ברכה ולמה לא באל"ף שהוא לשון ארירה אלא אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא הרי אני בורא אותו בלשון ברכה והלואי יעמוד.‏

[Zohar Vayigash](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%98#.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A9.D7.AA_.D7.95.D7.99.D7.92.D7.A9)

> עד דאתקיים כלא באת בי"ת דאיהו סימן ברכה, ובה אשתכלל עלמא ואתברי. ואי תימא דאל"ף איהו רישא דכל (אינון) אתוון, (לאו) יאות איהו, אלא בגין דאתקרי ביה ארור, (ובגין דאתקרי ביה ארור), בגין דא לא אתברי בה עלמא, ואף על גב דאל"ף איהו את דרזא עלאה, בגין דלא למיהב דוכתא לסטרא אחרא דאקרי ארור, לא אתברי בה עלמא, ואשתכלל בבית עלמא וביה אתברי.‏