# Two beginnings related to heavens and earth

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, midrash, parashat-bereishit, aleph-bet-letters

IIRC, there is a medrash conecting the first letter of torah (beit) + the word reshit by saying that with 2 beginnings (meaning the heavens and earth) the world came into existence. Does anyone happen to know a source for this?

Related: [Why the first letter of the Tenach is a Bet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73285/source-midrash-why-the-first-letter-of-the-tenach-is-a-bet)

Comment: This sounds very similar to an early Rashi in Bereishis where he cites the Midrash that Hashem "wanted" to create the world with strict judgement, and, foreseeing that mankind wouldn't be able to exist in such a world, He tempered it with mercy. I wonder if those two Midrashim are intended to play off of each other.

Comment: I've seen medrashim relating the "two beginnings" with "two worlds", but not to the heavens and earth. In fact, this medrash would pair with those who state the heavens and earth were created at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like *Ki B'Ko Hashem Tzur Olomin* - that the heaven & earth was created with a Yud and a Heh.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case. The source i'm looking for  explicitly says beit referring to heavens and earth, not yud or heh.